# Want to convert a component created with .map() to any another component so that .includes() can work on new component

Tags: reactjs

I am running below code in React `App.js` .

FilteredData contains data as below

```
const filteredData = [{ fruitname: 'apple', fruitprice: '200'},
{ fruitname: 'mango', fruitprice: '500'}];
```

The main App.js contains below code

```
import React, {
useState,
} from 'react';

function Fruits({ filteredData }) {


const DisplayData = filteredData.map(
(info) => (
  <div>
    <ul id="result" type="disc">
      <li>{info.fruitname}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

));



  const valuesnew =[...DisplayData.values()];
  const resultnew = valuesnew.includes('apple');

  return (
  <section>
  {String(resultnew)}
  </section>
  );
  }

App.propTypes = {
 filteredData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
fruitname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
fruitprice: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

 })),
};
export { App};
export default App;
```

The main agenda is that I need to check if 'apple' is present in filteredData (this data is coming from outside of app.js), to achieve that I am doing below

1. putting filteredData in a const DisplayData
2. converting DisplayData into an array valuesnew
3. using .includes() method on valuesnew

But .includes() method gives false even though 'apple' is present . So .includes() is not working on the component.

Comment: `<p>apple</p>` will never be equal to `apple`

Comment: @devpolo - Thanks for your response. If I want to check for presence of a specific text in a component that contains <p> or <li> elements, how can i use .includes? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes!!!! I  used edited solution which you suggested as below
function Fruits({ filteredData }) {
  return (
    <section>
      {filteredData.map((info) => {

        if (info.fruitname !== "apple") return null;

        return (
          <div>
            <ul id="result" type="disc">
              <li>{info.fruitname}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </section>
  )
}

IT WAS VERY HELPFUL, I am now able to proceed, Thanks a lot for the help! We can now close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) things in a array with the `find` method. Its gives you the current element from the array where you can access its props such as `fruitname`.

If the array contains a object with the `fruitname` of **apple** then it will return that object else it will return `undefined`. In this case we check if its not `undefined` and thus **true**.

You can use it like so

```js
const hasApple =
  filteredData.find((fruit) => fruit.fruitname === "apple") !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you are trying to accomplish but this may help:

```js
import { Children } from "react";

const ELEMENTS = [<p>apple</p>, <p>mango</p>, <p>banana</p>];

export default function App() {
  return Children.map(ELEMENTS, (child) => {
    if (child.props.children === "apple") {
      return child;
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```

EDIT:
Why don't you simply did it on the return?

```js
function Fruits({ filteredData }) {
  return (
    <section>
      {filteredData.map((info) => {

        if (info.fruitname !== "apple") return null;

        return (
          <div>
            <ul id="result" type="disc">
              <li>{info.fruitname}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my const elements looks like this

  const DisplayData = filteredData.map(
    (info) => (

      <div>
        <ul>

          <li>{info.fruitname}</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    ));

Comment: In this case,  how can I convert my code to look like below

const ELEMENTS = [<p>apple</p>, <p>mango</p>, <p>banana</p>];

'apple', 'banana' 'mango' are coming from filteredData and I am using .map and <li> to store it.

Comment: Why don't you add your html tags in your `return` and not in your `ELEMENT` variable?

Comment: I can remove those from ELEMENT variable, but filteredData is coming as a parameter to App.js

Terms.propTypes = {
  filteredData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    fruitname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fruitprice: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   
  })),
};

So i need to use a map to store the data from filterData to ELEMENT variable .

Comment: can you edit your question to reflect what you just describe?

Comment: looks like I cannot see your change

Comment: I have changed the question title, should I change the body too?

Comment: if possible. Yes please !

Comment: why are you using map and not find?

Comment: @devpolo - Apologies! i have now updated the question. Would Appreciate your help.